# How to create different popup (context) menus for each *type* of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

I was able to create a context menu for my QTreeWidget as below

```
QMenu* pContextMenu = new QMenu(this)
QTreeWidget* pTreeWidget = new QTreeWidget();
QAction* pOpenFile = new QAction(tr("Open A File"), pContextMenu);
pTreeWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);
pTreeWidget->addAction(pOpenFile);
```

But I want a different popup for a branch than a leaf. How do I assign a different popup depending on the type of widgetitem clicked?

My tree:

- Branch1  <-- Popup1

  - Leaf1
  - Leaf2 <-- Popup2
- Branch2

  - Branch3

    - Leaf1

QWidget::actions() is not listed as virtual. Else I would have derived my own class from QTreeWidget & reimplemented actions().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Method 1: Override QTreeWidget

A context menu assigned to the `QTreeWidget` itself will not let you have different context menus for different items, as you have discovered.

As the Qt item views don't have special API for context menus, you have to implement this yourself. Fortunately, it's not very difficult; you just need to:

1. Create a subclass of `QTreeWidget`.
2. Connect the `customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)` signal to a custom slot.
3. Display the desired context menu.

I've posted a [complete working example](https://gist.github.com/3906292). Some details to note include:

- `QTreeWidgetItem` provides a handy `type` property to let you identify items easily without casting, string parsing, or other awkward/fragile methods.
- Custom `QTreeWidgetItem` type values should be greater than or equal to `QTreeWidgetItem::UserType`.
- When displaying a context menu, you must pass a global position to `exec()`. To correctly map from a position in the widget's space in the slot, you must use the item's viewport widget.

---

#### Method 2: Override QItemDelegate (and QTreeWidget ...)

An alternate method is to implement your own `QAbstractItemDelegate` subclass, and assign it to your tree widget. In your item delegate, you can override `editorEvent()` to handle mouse presses in the same way.

Although this approach frres is actually more in line with Qt's item view API design, there are a few key disadvantages to this approach:

- Item delegates use `QModelIndex` objects to represent items. To convert to a `QTreeWidgetItem`, you must use the `QTreeWidget::itemFromIndex()` method. Unfortunately, this is *protected*, so it will actually require you to subclass `QTreeWidget` anyway to provide this API for your delegate. This adds some more boilerplate complexity to your code.
- The `editorEvent()` hook is invoked before the item view handles the event. This means that you can't easily display a context menu and allow the default behavior at the same time (such as selecting the item that was right-clicked).
- Since the `editorEvent()` handler sees all kinds of different events, you must be even more careful to handle them correctly. You must also be careful not to let this monolithic handler grow out of control if your behaviors are complicated.

The core code is very similar, but again, there's a bit more boilerplate. I've posted [an example of this approach](https://gist.github.com/3906464), as well.

Comment: In first approach instead of listenting for mouse events, more focused approach is to set use setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu); on QTreeWidget. This will cause QWidget::customContextMenuRequested ( const QPoint & pos ) to be emitted where you can place current content of MyTreeWidget::showContextMenu().

Comment: Thanks guys. I am still working on it because we have a not-so-great designer based system. I will mark this as the answer after I am done. Sorry divanov but I will upvote yours.

Comment: @jmk Worked. Except that I had to create the QMenus (for each type) in MyTreeWidget c'tor & then call <respective_menu>.exec() in the switch. You may want to change that in your example. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Whether to create menus in constructor or on in the slot is just memory consumption/performance dilemma. But I believe for this case menus are created rarely, it's not heavy operation, so jmk's code is preferable as you will benefit from smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified jmk's code slightly to show how this can be done with

setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu) and customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&) signal.

mytreewidget.h

```
#include <QTreeWidget>

static const int ItemType1 = QTreeWidgetItem::UserType + 1;
static const int ItemType2 = QTreeWidgetItem::UserType + 2;

class MyTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void showContextMenu(const QPoint &pos);
};
```

mytreewidget.cpp:

```
#include "mytreewidget.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>

MyTreeWidget::MyTreeWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
    setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
            SLOT(showContextMenu(const QPoint&)));
}

void MyTreeWidget::showContextMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
  QMenu menu;

  QTreeWidgetItem* item = itemAt(pos);
  switch (item->type()) {
  case ItemType1:
    menu.addAction("This is a type 1");
    break;

  case ItemType2:
    menu.addAction("This is a type 2");
    break;
  }

  menu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mytreewidget.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyTreeWidget w;

    // Add test items.
    w.addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList("A (type 1)"),
                                          ItemType1));
    w.addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList("B (type 1)"),
                                          ItemType1));

    w.addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList("C (type 2)"),
                                      ItemType2));
    w.addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList("D (type 2)"),
                                          ItemType2));
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've revised my answer as well. (You could've also edited my answer, since they are so similar, to reduce confusion.)

Comment: I cannot since you've posted code on external to stackoverflow github.

Comment: Actually, you can! Gists can be forked, and you can make your own modifications and change the link. :)

Comment: I just believe that posting small code examples on external services is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's an external dependency, but I try to word my answers so that they don't actually *depend* on them, just provide a convenient reference. I prefer to answer with explanations, rather than just reply with working code, but I can definitely see your point. I wish Stack Overflow had collapsible code boxes.

Comment: In my experience the best way to answer a programming question is a well structured code with comments in it.